# Is there a window manager that allows tabs of multiple different programs in one window? (Like Windows 10 Sets)?

Tags: window-manager, window, tabs

I installed the Windows 10 preview releases awhile back because I wanted to try the Sets feature that was being worked on. Sadly, this was removed from the beta releases, and has not returned.

Is there a Linux window manager that has this capability? (Using tabs of multiple different programs in one window.)

Comment: That's sort of what gnome workspaces are but I think not exactly the interface you want it in.

Comment: Examples of alternative Windows products: http://windowtabs.com (Open Souce), https://www.stardock.com/products/groupy ,  https://www.nurgo-software.com/products/tidytabs , and TaskSpace (scroll down) http://www.systemgoods.com/ . Splendid idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This table of [Window Managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers) shows Linux Window Managers with tabbed windows include:

[xmonad](https://xmonad.org/), [wmii](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wmii/), [Window Maker](https://www.windowmaker.org/), WMFS, PekWM, [Ion](https://tuomov.iki.fi/software/), [i3](https://i3wm.org/), [FVWM](http://www.fvwm.org), [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/), and [Compiz](https://launchpad.net/compiz).

Some Desktop Environments are locked in to a specific Window Manager (e.g., Cinnamon), but [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/) and [KDE](https://kde.org/) are not.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with that windows 10 feature, but it looks similar to window manager tabbing which had been around for quite a while.

I first encountered it in fluxbox over 10 years ago, but plenty of other WMs have that feature. It basically allows you to drag and drop a window onto another and the window manager will tab them together.

http://fluxbox-wiki.org/category/howtos/en/Tabs.html

You can see it in action here
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zENMoS1BbwM

Answer (score 1):

For linux compiz there is a plugin exactly for that, however it might not be available at the time being in every compiz version

http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Group